# What is RTTVAR in NMap?

Tags: nmap

I find a lot of sources explaining how to get rid of the following message:

```
RTTVAR has grown to over 2.3 seconds, decreasing to 2.0
```

But

- What exactly is RTTVAR(Round Trip Time Variance)?
- What is happening here?

Comment: When tcp is used the sender needs a retransmission timeout, to know when data needs to be resended if it got lost. The retransmission timeout (RTO) is calculated from two variables: the estimated Smoothed Round Trip Time (SRTT) and its variance (RTTVAR). You can read everything else in [RFC 6298](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6298).

Comment: RTTVAR is not specific to nmap and is a TCP thing.